# Query string on LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, query-string

I'm trying to do the next thing: i have the next code on c#:

```
b.Text = myDataContext.purchases.Count().ToString();
```

I have page for example: `items.aspx?nID=144`

How can i can I construct a linq query which will take the querystring parameter and check the value from the `items` table by the `id (nID)` that show on the address?

The table have the design for example: `id, title, bla, main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lambda expressions:

```
int nID;
string qs = QueryString["nID"];
if (Int32.TryParse(qs, nID)
    myDataContext.purchases.Where(p => p.id == nID);
    // Other options if nID is a primary key
    //myDataContext.purchases.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == nID);
    //myDataContext.purchases.SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == nID);
```

By LINQ query:

```
int nID;
string qs = QueryString["nID"];
if (Int32.TryParse(qs, nID)
    var purchase = from p in myDataContext.purchases
        where p.id == nID
        select p;
```

Comment: still I would NOT mix UI/ASP.NET logic like getting the nID with the query itself, I would have queries in another business related class.

Comment: @Davide Piras Well, I solve one problem - how to make a query. I think @Bside can easy upgrade the code. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are just trying to obtain the `nID` param from the `QueryString` and then reuse its value in some linq query to fetch the data from the database. You can achieve it with the code below (inside a ASPX page):

```
int nID;

string value = Request.QueryString["nID"];
if(int.TryParse(value, out nID))
{
    // your linq query
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i have another question about the same code that i post on the question:  b.Text = myDataContext.purchases.Count().ToString();  ....... how can i do here : where main = true; ?

Comment: I think you should create a separate post for the second question. It will be easier to find it and more people can give you their input.